# What's going on with the electrical wiring (or devices) in this room?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, interference

I was soldering components onto a circuit board that was placed on a rubber-like soldering mat on a table. Simultaneously, I was listening to audio from my desktop computer, using wired headphones.
The computer and the soldering iron were plugged into different power outlets within the same room.
I hear electric pops through the headphones every time the tip of the soldering iron and the soldering wire simultaneously touch the metal parts of the components that I’m soldering.

Is this normal, and is it something to worry about? What is it a sign of?

Comment: Either static or RF emissions. Hard to say without knowing more about your solder project. At an rate, not really a home improvement topic.

Comment: I suspect your soldering iron is causing a ground fault.  Try with a different soldering iron, preferably new out of the package. As @isherwood points out this isn’t exactly on topic—you can make it more on topic by clicking edit and instead asking if there could be an issue with the plug involved or the circuit feeding it.   Also was the circuit board grounded?  You say it was on a rubber mat, which implies no grounding, but was it connected to anything?

Comment: @isherwood The contents of my soldering project are irrelevant, because I can produce the sound merely by touching the tin wire with the solder tip directly, it doesn't require the solderable component project in between. I thought it would be more appropriate for this board than the "electrical engineering" board for example: anyone who's experienced at electrical wiring related home improvement might see what's happening here. It's about how this room was built and what's in it.

Comment: @Tyson What technically happens when there's a ground fault?
This soldering iron is only a few months old, albeit inexpensive. The building is so old that the power outlets in the dry rooms don't have a ground pin (contrary to what would be mandatory for new installations today).
The circuit board is not grounded, and it was in the center of the rubber mat. I was also only using the board as a stand for assembling a series of components together, so the components aren't even soldered onto the board, and there are no power sources or anything complicated going on on it.

Comment: That does add a lot of valuable information that really should be made permanent via an edit to the question.  I’m not certain a ground fault is occurring anymore, but to specifically answer the question, a ground fault is a leak of current, in most cases 100% of the current delivered via the hot wire returns via the neutral wire, if any current leaks anywhere that is a fault to ground.  Does the capacitance of your body have effect? Specifically what are you touching? Try holding the solder with insulated needlenose instead of your bare hand. Does this change anything? Are you grounded?

Comment: You stated the wiring to the room has no ground. Is the desktop computer grounded?

Comment: Do any of these receptacles have 3-pin sockets? If not, how did you manage to plug in the PC?

Comment: @Tyson Okay I see... Let me test what you suggest and report back.
All of the plugs in devices like these have a ground pin available, as does the extension cord that's mandatory for the soldering iron as its own cord is of a completely useless length. But the sockets on the walls don't have ground contact because they were made before the earthing standard.

Comment: @Harper You just plug it in. The sockets/plugs with ground contact are Schuko standard, so there's two pins plus a ground contact which is not a pin per se. The old standard before this was the same except without the ground contact. According to a certain national website informing consumers about household electricity stuff, it's illegal to have unearthed sockets in bathrooms and kitchens etc but the old style sockets in dry rooms can be of the old style and it is safe to use them with devices that have ground pins in their plugs.

Comment: @Tyson Okay, if I use the solder tip to touch the tin wire coil that lies on the rubber mat and I'm not touching the wire with my hands, the contact with the iron does not produce popping sounds. If I hold it with tweezers (PT ESD-15), I get popping sounds. If I put a thin rubber mouse pad between my hand and the tweezers, the iron touching the tin wire held by those tweezers will not make popping sounds. Does this mean that electricity from the solder tip is going via the tin wire through me, and... where to from there, and what does it have to do with the headphones?

Comment: @Tyson and I'm not grounded. Just sitting in a chair at the table really.

Comment: Yea the computer needs to be grounded.  Safety-wise they apparently have exceptions in your county.  Those exceptions don’t provide a ground path static and RF noise tho.  BTW, what country?

Comment: @Tyson Finland. Well these are the current laws. I read that it's forbidden to have both grounded and ungrounded sockets in the same room, what matters is that they're either or. But ungrounded plugs are forbidden now. If I understood correctly, if you had one device plugged in to grounded and one into ungrounded socket and one device becomes faulty, touching both devices simultaneously could result into an electric shock. This is why I'm not going to, for example, put an extension cord to the computer's cord just to plug into the grounded socket in the bathroom or kitchen.